# Spring boot OneToMany with JoinColumn not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities below:

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode( of = {"journeyId"})
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class ContentManagementJourney {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "JOURNEY_ID", unique = true)
  private String journeyId;

  @Column(name = "JOURNEY_NAME")
  private String journeyName;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "JOURNEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "JOURNEY_ID")
  private Collection<ContentManagementStatus> screens = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"menuId"})
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class ContentManagementStatus {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "JOURNEY_ID")
  private String journeyId;

  @Column(name = "MENU_ID", unique = true)
  private String menuId;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date lastUpdate;
}
```

I execute the delete and update query on the table `ContentManagementJourney`, the item of the table was updated or deleted successfully. But unfortunately, the item in `ContentManagementStatus` with the same `journeyId` was not deleted. What is happening here? I also can't use a bidirectional mechanism because I don't want my `ContentManagementJourney` to be shown every time I query/select from the `ContentManagementStatus` table.

I'm using this spring version:

```json
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
  implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4'
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Check the executed logs. How do you do delete and upate?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I executed the query using mysql workbench with raw query `delete from content_management_journey where journey_id = 'something';`

Comment: What you do in your Java code with JPA annotations does not affect the database. So when you delete from `content_management_journey` using an SQL statement in MySQL Workbench, it is not automatically going to delete the linked `content_management_status` records. The database, and MySQL Workbench, know nothing about the JPA cascade settings you put in your Java code.

Comment: This code has a few problems, first being that the mappings are not correct - you have the ContentManagementStatus. JOURNEY_ID column writable through multiple java properties (the ContentManagementJourney.screens collection as well as each ContentManagementStatus.journeyId string). One side or the other needs to be marked read-only - chances are it isn't being set the way you think it should in the database because of this. Also check that, if using JPA to remove ContentManagementJourney instead of your own queries, that the screens collection has values - JPA will only delete what it knows

Comment: @Jesper well in that case how can I ensure that JPA creates the necessary foreign key relationship so that the update/delete cascade works seamlessly when I perform operations in the database?

Comment: @Chris Could you provide a sample of the code for the mappings between ContentManagementJourney and ContentManagementStatus entities? It would be really helpful for me to better understand the issue and provide more specific guidance on resolving the problems you've mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use bulk update/delete then no cascading will happen because this bypasses the persistence context.

Cascading is only happening when using the methods of the EntityManager.

Comment: In JPA, if I execute a raw query directly after creating JPA entities outside the application scope, cascading won't occur since the persistence context is bypassed. On the other hand, with another ORM like TypeORM, transactions involving foreign keys would work as expected, updating or deleting linked values automatically. How can I achieve similar behavior in JPA where cascading occurs even after executing raw queries?

Comment: You can't. It's not possible